# What can we say about the dimension of $[ E : F]$ if $F$ is finite and $f \in F[x]$ min. polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

suppose I have a field $F$ and $\alpha \notin F$. $F$ is finite so $char(F)$ is some $p \in \mathbb{N}$

when I have a minimal polynomial $f_\alpha \in F[x]$ with $deg(f_\alpha)=n$ then the dimension of $[F(\alpha) : F ] = n$ is there also some relation to the $char(F)$ ?

Comment: What sort of relation? The formulae you write down are independent of $\operatorname{char} F$.

Comment: Yes, the prime field is in both cases $\mathbb{F}_p$, hence they have characteristic $p$.

Comment: i was wondering if I can estimate $n$ somehow by $p$

Comment: @user342539 $n$ can be chosen to be any positive integer you like and  does not depend on $p$.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that if $F$ is a finite field, then for each integer $n$ there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $F$. So we cannot have any connection between the characteristic of $F$ and $n$.

Comment: Completely unlike the situation with the reals!

Comment: @Lubin Maybe I'm missing your point, but the above is entirely similar to the situation with rationals, so it seems like characteristic plays no essential role here.

Comment: To tell the truth, @ErickWong, I don’t know now what I had in mind when I wrote that. But this we do know: if a field has only one (proper) algebraic extension, then the degree of that extension is two, and the characteristic is zero.